# How do I use the mouse to click on a cell in the parent window's Qtablewidget to get a value, and then fill it into the child's QlineEdit?

Tags: pyqt5, python-3.7

I want to do a function, kind of like insert function in Excel,just like this:
[image]

Now I'm confused about how to use the mouse to fetch data in the parent window (Qtablewidget) and fill the data into the lineEdit that the mouse cursor stays in the child window.In other words, how do I know which component the cursor is in.

Here is MainWindow.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Form(object):
    def setupUi(self, Form):
        Form.setObjectName("Form")
        Form.resize(1191, 941)
        self.verticalLayout_3 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Form)
        self.verticalLayout_3.setObjectName("verticalLayout_3")
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout()
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Form)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton)
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame)
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_2)
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(940, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.tabWidget = QtWidgets.QTabWidget(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setTabPosition(QtWidgets.QTabWidget.West)
        self.tabWidget.setObjectName("tabWidget")
        self.tab = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab.setObjectName("tab")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.tab)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.tableWidget = QtWidgets.QTableWidget(self.tab)
        self.tableWidget.setRowCount(5)
        self.tableWidget.setObjectName("tableWidget")
        self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(4)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(0, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(1, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(2, item)
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem()
        self.tableWidget.setHorizontalHeaderItem(3, item)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.tableWidget)
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab, "")
        self.tab_2 = QtWidgets.QWidget()
        self.tab_2.setObjectName("tab_2")
        self.tabWidget.addTab(self.tab_2, "")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.tabWidget)
        self.verticalLayout_3.addLayout(self.verticalLayout_2)

        self.retranslateUi(Form)
        self.tabWidget.setCurrentIndex(0)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Form)

    def retranslateUi(self, Form):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Form.setWindowTitle(_translate("Form", "Form"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("Form", "PushButton"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(0)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "A"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(1)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "B"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(2)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "C"))
        item = self.tableWidget.horizontalHeaderItem(3)
        item.setText(_translate("Form", "D"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab), _translate("Form", "Tab 1"))
        self.tabWidget.setTabText(self.tabWidget.indexOf(self.tab_2), _translate("Form", "Tab 2"))
```

Here is ChildWindow.py:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_Dialog(object):
    def setupUi(self, Dialog):
        Dialog.setObjectName("Dialog")
        Dialog.resize(558, 331)
        self.verticalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(Dialog)
        self.verticalLayout_2.setObjectName("verticalLayout_2")
        self.frame = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame.setObjectName("frame")
        self.verticalLayout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self.frame)
        self.verticalLayout.setObjectName("verticalLayout")
        self.groupBox = QtWidgets.QGroupBox(self.frame)
        self.groupBox.setObjectName("groupBox")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.groupBox)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit.setObjectName("lineEdit")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_2 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_2.setObjectName("label_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_2, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_2 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_2.setObjectName("lineEdit_2")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_2, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.label_3 = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.groupBox)
        self.label_3.setObjectName("label_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.label_3, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.lineEdit_3 = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.groupBox)
        self.lineEdit_3.setObjectName("lineEdit_3")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.lineEdit_3, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.groupBox)
        self.frame_2 = QtWidgets.QFrame(self.frame)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_2.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.frame_2.setObjectName("frame_2")
        self.horizontalLayout = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_2)
        self.horizontalLayout.setObjectName("horizontalLayout")
        spacerItem = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(88, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem)
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_2)
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.horizontalLayout.addWidget(self.pushButton_3)
        spacerItem1 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(87, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout.addItem(spacerItem1)
        self.verticalLayout.addWidget(self.frame_2)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame)
        self.line = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.line.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.HLine)
        self.line.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Sunken)
        self.line.setObjectName("line")
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.line)
        self.frame_3 = QtWidgets.QFrame(Dialog)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.StyledPanel)
        self.frame_3.setFrameShadow(QtWidgets.QFrame.Raised)
        self.frame_3.setObjectName("frame_3")
        self.horizontalLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QHBoxLayout(self.frame_3)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.setObjectName("horizontalLayout_2")
        spacerItem2 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(150, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem2)
        self.pushButton_4 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.pushButton_4.setObjectName("pushButton_4")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_4)
        self.pushButton_5 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.frame_3)
        self.pushButton_5.setObjectName("pushButton_5")
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addWidget(self.pushButton_5)
        spacerItem3 = QtWidgets.QSpacerItem(149, 20, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Expanding, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Minimum)
        self.horizontalLayout_2.addItem(spacerItem3)
        self.verticalLayout_2.addWidget(self.frame_3)

        self.retranslateUi(Dialog)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(Dialog)

    def retranslateUi(self, Dialog):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        Dialog.setWindowTitle(_translate("Dialog", "IF_1"))
        self.groupBox.setTitle(_translate("Dialog", "IF"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Logical_text"))
        self.label_2.setText(_translate("Dialog", "True_value"))
        self.label_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Flase_value"))
        self.pushButton_3.setToolTip(_translate("Dialog", "<html><head/><body><p>打开下一级嵌套</p></body></html>"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Nested"))
        self.pushButton_4.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Save"))
        self.pushButton_5.setText(_translate("Dialog", "Close"))
```

Here is the logical file:

```
import sys, traceback

from PyQt5 import QtCore
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMenu, QTableWidgetItem, QWidget, QDialog, QMessageBox
from PyQt5.QtCore import QObject, Qt, pyqtSignal

from UI.test import test
from UI.test.IF_1 import Ui_Dialog


class IF_window(QDialog, Ui_Dialog):
    Signal = pyqtSignal(str)

    def __init__(self):
        super(IF_window, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)
        #self.pushButton_3.clicked.connect(self.btnclick)
        self.pushButton_4.clicked.connect(self.trans_data)
        self.pushButton_5.clicked.connect(self.close)

    def trans_data(self):
        a = self.lineEdit.text()
        b = self.lineEdit_2.text()
        c = self.lineEdit_3.text()
        d = 'IF(' + a + ',' + b + ',' + c + ')'
        self.Signal.emit(d)
        QMessageBox.information(self, "notice", "Save success！", QMessageBox.Yes)

    def btnclick(self):
        try:
            self.form = IF_window_2()
            #styleFile = 'E:\Development\Study\Qss\qss.css'
            #qssStyle = CommonHelper.readQss(styleFile)
            #self.form.setStyleSheet(qssStyle)
            self.form.Signal_1.connect(self.signal_text_1)
            self.form.Signal_2.connect(self.signal_text_2)
            self.form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
            self.form.show()
        except:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            a = repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                                exc_traceback))
            QMessageBox.information(self, "notice", a, QMessageBox.Yes)

    def signal_text_1(self, d):
        self.lineEdit_2.setText(d)

    def signal_text_2(self, d):
        self.lineEdit_3.setText(d)

class MyMainWindow(QWidget, test.Ui_Form):
    def __init__(self):
        super(MyMainWindow, self).__init__()
        self.setupUi(self)

        self.tableWidget.setContextMenuPolicy(Qt.CustomContextMenu)
        self.tableWidget.customContextMenuRequested.connect(self.generateMenu)

    def generateMenu(self, pos):

        try:
            column_num = -1
            row_sum = []
            column_sum = []
            for i in self.tableWidget.selectionModel().selection().indexes():
                row_num = i.row()
                column_num = i.column()
                row_sum.append(row_num)
                column_sum.append(column_num)

            if column_num != -1:
                menu = QMenu()
                item1 = menu.addAction(u"IF_function")
                action = menu.exec_(self.tableWidget.mapToGlobal(pos))

                if action == item1:
                    self.form = IF_window()
                    #styleFile = 'E:\Development\Study\Qss\qss.css'
                    #qssStyle = CommonHelper.readQss(styleFile)
                    #self.form.setStyleSheet(qssStyle)
                    self.form.Signal.connect(self.get_data)
                    self.form.setWindowFlags(QtCore.Qt.WindowStaysOnTopHint)
                    self.form.show()
                else:
                    return

        except:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            a = repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                                exc_traceback))
            QMessageBox.information(self, "notice", a, QMessageBox.Yes)

    def get_data(self, d):
        try:
            row_sum = []
            column_sum = []
            for i in self.tableWidget.selectionModel().selection().indexes():
                row_num = i.row()
                column_num = i.column()
                row_sum.append(row_num)
                column_sum.append(column_num)
            data = QTableWidgetItem(d)
            self.tableWidget.setItem(row_sum[0], column_sum[0], data)

            print(row_sum[0], column_sum[0])

        except:
            exc_type, exc_value, exc_traceback = sys.exc_info()
            a = repr(traceback.format_exception(exc_type, exc_value,
                                                exc_traceback))
            QMessageBox.information(self, "notice", a, QMessageBox.Yes)


class CommonHelper:
    def __init__(self):
        pass

    @staticmethod
    def readQss(style):
        with open(style, 'r', encoding='UTF-8') as f:
            return f.read()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = MyMainWindow()
    #styleFile = 'E:\Development\Study\Qss\qss.css'
    #qssStyle = CommonHelper.readQss(styleFile)
    #win.setStyleSheet(qssStyle)
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: OK, I have updated my question.By the way,English is not my native language, so I use translation software to communicate. Because the translation software cannot translate well, I have great difficulty in consulting official documents.So I don't even know how I'm going to achieve my needs.Please forgive a rookie's helplessness

Comment: You posted two identical .ui files. Also these aren't used anywhere in the main python file so I assume you converted these to python first. Could you post the definitions of `Ui_Dialog`  and `Ui_Form` from these python files?

Comment: Sorry for my mistake, I have updated the.ui code to.py code.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem by adding a clicked signal to the childwindow's LineEdit , which fires a text signal .The parentwindow takes the signal and uses the text to determine which child's LineEdit was clicked, then gets the value of the parent window's clicked cell,and  simply setText().